# What is the best way to draw text along with geometry?

Tags: wpf, text, geometry, draw

In WPF, I'm starting to use classes such as LineGeometry, EllipseGeometry, GeometryGroup, Path... in order to draw 2D graphics. I chose these over shapes because I saw it could be faster thanks to the freezing feature.

I need to draw text along with geometry, with specific fonts. The text needs to be positionnable with the same coordinate system as the geometry. And I need to be able to apply a transform such as RotateTransform.

**What would be the best way?** I've run across the GlyphRunDrawing class but it's really complicated.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: If you run into the "is obsolete" error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45765980/formattedtext-formttedtext-is-obsolete-use-the-pixelsperdip-override

Answer (score 39, accepted):

To create a text geometry just use FormattedText.BuildGeometry, for example, to get a geometry of "Text to display" in font Tahoma size 16 pixels at point (5,5) use:

```
    FormattedText text = new FormattedText("Text to display",
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
        FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
        new Typeface("Tahoma"),
        16,
        Brushes.Black);
    Geometry geometry = text.BuildGeometry(new Point(5, 5));
```

If you need to do this in XAML you can wrap up this code in a MarkupExtention